# the meaning of 「ということになります。」

Tags: meaning

I'm trying to understand the meaning of 「ということになります」

Context:

> 私の言葉の範囲が、そのまま私の世界の限界ということになります。 - The limits of my language are the limits of my world.

I understand the normal usage of

> という

> こと

> なります

But I can't understand they're working together in this sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts:

- **ということ（は）** or in other cases（というものは）= (I conclude) that ~, the fact is that ~
- **になります**= becomes

ということは is used in complex pieces of writing to focus the reader on key points - for example, the substance of a remark, piece of knowledge or an event. In simpler sentences it isn't needed.

When the writer uses といことは , their aim is to either state that they think that

1. X is **impossible**, or
2. X is **a fact**.

In the sample sentence, it seems that (2) is relevant.

It may be that the writer wants to draw a parallel between the two uses of 'limit', 範囲 and 限界, and conclude that 範囲 is in fact a 限界.

- 私の言葉の**範囲**が,  The limits of my language
- そのまま  left unchanged / as they currently are
- **限界**ということになります。 **become in fact / become so that** they are the limits to
- 私の世界の  my world

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to understand ということになります is by viewing XがYということになります as a set phrase that concludes that X implies or can be rephrased in terms of Y.

You could think of it like this:

> XがYということになります = X is, in other words, Y

Or, if applied to your sample sentence:

> 私の言葉の範囲 is, in other words, 私の世界の限界